# Post from Java(springboot) to DB using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, spring

Heres my Controller for the Class (tecnico)

```
@RestController
public class TecnicoController {

@Autowired
TecnicoRepository tecnicoRepository;

@Autowired
private final TecnicoService tecnicoService;

@Inject
public TecnicoController(final TecnicoService tecnicoService) {
    this.tecnicoService = tecnicoService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get/tecnico/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object queryTecnico(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Tecnico tecnico = tecnicoService.getTecnico(id);
    if (tecnico == null)
        return "No encontrado";
    return tecnico;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get/tecnico/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object queryTecnico() {
    List<Tecnico> tecnico = tecnicoRepository.findAll();
    return tecnico;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/post/tecnico", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Tecnico editTecnico(@RequestBody @Valid final Tecnico tecnico) {
    return tecnicoRepository.save(tecnico);
}
}
```

And here´s the angular file

[Angularjs file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jMgYr5eg)

My question is how should I fix this html to make the post method work properly?
Im really new to angularJS and I´m having a hard time figuring it out.
[HTML PAGE](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PPDpaS9U)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Json back reference was causing the data to no get posted on the json output @JsonBackReference simply commenting it was enough.